# how to send the id value from a link when clicked to php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

i have many `forms` in a single page, there is a button that opens up a text editor that was hidden with the purpose of updating a text file accordingly to a user_id
so i iterate through all users and get many of these:

```
<form action="admin/edittoken.php" method="POST">
    <td><a id="'.$result[0]['user_id'].'" onclick="toggle_visibility(\'feedDiv\');">
        <button onclick="toggle_visibility(\'feed\');" type="button">Feed
        </button><a/></td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="password" >Apply Changes</button></td>
    <td><input name="first_name" class="smallInput" value="'.$result[0]['first_name'].'" type="text" /></td>
</form>
```

as you can see when i click this link and there is one per each form i show a div with id = `feedDiv`

`<a id="'.$result[0]['user_id'].'" onclick="toggle_visibility(\'feedDiv\');">`

the id of the `<a>` is the user id and with that data i can pull up the right txt file to edit

**SO MY GOAL IS:**

1. get the id of the link that was clicked when requesting to show the div ( the user_id)
2. place that id in between php for PDO to query and display the right txt file

this is the php

```
<div id="feedDiv">
    <form method="POST" action="admin/edittoken.php">
        <textarea id="feed" name="information">
            <?php $user=/ /the a Link Clicked Id Value is the user_id //need help
            here $filename=/ /equal to the PDO Result to get the right text file $handle=f
            open($filename, "r"); $contents=f read($handle, filesize($filename)); fclose($handle);
            echo $contents; ?>
        </textarea>
        <button class="btn  btn-primary yellow" type="submit" name="feed">Send Feed</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Javascript so far...

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if (e.style.display == 'block') e.style.display = 'none';
    else e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/EC6b4/1/

Comment: if there is a quick better way im open for suggestions :) thanks

Comment: tagged with jquery but your not using it?

Comment: @Gunr, first, can you please tell me location of the <div id="feedDiv" >, i mean, it is in the same page, or a separate page, 
Second, show the defination of the function toggle_visibility,

Comment: @Dagon for ajax purposes

Comment: @SAM its all in the same file, ill work a jsfiddle

Comment: like the reast of js there is ajax with or without using jquery.

Comment: @Gunr Jesra, when you display the `textarea` element don't expect tha PHP code get executed in that moment. You want to get dynamic information with static code. Use `this.id` inside the `onclick` attribute of the `<a>` tag to pass the id or just use JQuery for listening to `click` events on anchors and do the rest there.

Comment: @GunrJesra, do one thing, use ajax concept in  toggle_visibility after  e.style.display = 'block'; line, and pass the user_id  ie, 
<a id="'.$result[0]['user_id'].'" onclick="toggle_visibility(\'feedDiv\', this.id);">
<div id="feedDiv" ></div>

and load the result of the ajax inbetween

Comment: @Sebastian im a newbie and i dont know what you mean by "Use `this.id`"

Comment: @SAM http://jsfiddle.net/EC6b4/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a id="'.$result[0]['user_id'].'" onclick="toggle_visibility(\'feedDiv\', this.id);">


function toggle_visibility(id, user_id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';

$.post("userdetail.php", { userid: user_id },
  function(data){
    $('#'+id).html(data);
  });

}
```

userdetail.php contails :

```
<form method="POST" action="admin/edittoken.php"> 
    <textarea id="feed" name="information">
    <?php
            $user = $_POST['userid']//the a Link Clicked Id Value is the user_id //need help here
            $filename = //equal to the PDO Result to get the right text file
                    $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
            $contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
            fclose($handle);
            echo $contents;
        ?>
        </textarea>
        <button class="btn  btn-primary yellow" type="submit" name="feed"  >Send Feed</button>  
        </form>
```

/////
and your placeholder will be like

```
<div id="feedDiv" ></div>
```

Comment: wait you set GET here didnt you -> `$('#'+id).load('userdetail.php?userid='+user_id);` and the form `method="POST"` or is post just like get

Comment: @sorry for mistake, you can use $.post instead http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/
please refer the edited code above
One more point, try to include latest jquery.js file

Comment: THANKS:) so you can mix jquery between javascript functions? mm i did not know that and honestly i feel stupid, im unfamiliar with ajax, what is happening here `$('#'+id).html(data);` ? where is it putting html data? or is it the response, if it is, then this response is ready when the div is showing aint it? i mean the function is going to perform ajax call to the file, the file will perform the job, so i need ro remove my original feedDiv? because when clicked im going to get it from userdetails.php right? lastly if im right in all of this, would the textarea be ready when i click it

Comment: @GunrJesra, 
1. you can mix jquery between javascript functions : YES.
2. $('#'+id).html(data); : get the response and place in feedDiv. ie ., <div id="feedDiv" ></div>.
3.so i need ro remove my original feedDiv : Yes, keep it like <div id="feedDiv" ></div>.
4. would the textarea be ready when i click it : For that you have use like $("button[name=feed]").on('click', function(){ //Code goes here for Send feed});.

Comment: this is where im going crazy @SAM `$('#'+id).html(data)` why `#'+id?` which div is that, i mean id equals a number, its the user_id gathered from the a>id, that dont make sense shouldnt it be `'#feedDiv'` ?